# Proportions in Venn Diagrams

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$P$, $L$ and $G$ are 3 different games and a player can play any 1, 2 or 3 of them. I have complete data for $P$ and $L$ , but only have 86% of the trials for $G$ have been completed. I want to figure out what the Venn diagram for game play will look like when I have finalized data for $G$, but don't know how to set the problem up.

I know the value for $0.86G$ and the expected value for $G$ as well as the other values as related to $0.86G$.

I have the play data for these values:
  $0.86G   =  13,651 $ 
      $G   =  15,873 $ 
      $L   =  31,792 $
      $P   = 137,943 $
  $0.86G+L =   5,600 $ 
  $0.86G+P =  17,686 $ 
      $P+L =  38,681 $ 
 $0.86G+P+L = 25,611 $

And want to know these values as they relate to $1G$:
$L$, $P$, $LG$, $PG$, $PL$, $PLG$

I suppose $L$, $P$ and $PL$ would stay the same (since they are final results, unlike G).

If $\frac{0.86G * 100}{86} = G$,
$G$ is 43% of $L$,
$G$ is 10% of $P$,
$L$ is 23% of $P$.

And this is where I'm stuck. Can someone explain the generic formulas for figuring out the adjusted values to me?

Thank you for any help, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you will have to specify a lot more detail about what these figures and variables represent.

Comment: @naslundx I edited the question to try and make it more clear. Sorry for the previous ambiguity.

Comment: Update: I found a Venn diagram solver and used the formulas on that page to organize the data in a better way, then figured out how to solve for the values I needed. I'll try to post the answer when I'm past my deadlines and have some time.